# (ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [300, 3] ) In text classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I'm new to python, trying to work with text classification. However, whenever I try to fit my data I get an error, It's clear I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is. Can someone explain me the error I am getting?

```
from nltk.corpus import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
#assign each text files contained in a folder named : 'x' with the category 'x'.
#result of this line is capturing manual categorization of corpus into 0, 1, 2 classes, to train later.
#Training Folder conatin three folders of classes: 0, 1, 2, each is treated by reader as a category
#and each folder contain 100 files in txt formar.
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('~/CorpusMain/Training/',
                                                                                 r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')

text = []
for file in reader.fileids():
    text.append(reader.raw(fileids=file))

myarray = np.asarray(text)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(myarray, reader.categories())
print(X_train_tfidf.shape)
print(X_train_tfidf)


from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                    ('clf', LinearSVC()),])
text_clf = text_clf.fit(text, reader.categories())
```

This is my whole output:

```
(300, 35452)
  (0, 13656)    0.116989332372
  (0, 23881)    0.198926409043
  (0, 16891)    0.0976295590378
  (0, 12971)    0.227522474834
  (0, 3584) 0.00403800859194
  (0, 17447)    0.116688675696
  (0, 7976) 0.00361099027578
  (0, 4949) 0.200037729764
  (0, 12900)    0.0470607385753
  (0, 8365) 0.170168848649
  (0, 35116)    0.00591313296587
  (0, 34532)    0.0300031821031
  (0, 28444)    0.0103225881505
  (0, 7775) 0.0118262659317
  (0, 35347)    0.00591313296587
  (0, 31378)    0.0095967062934
  (0, 31367)    0.00233592956364
  (0, 32288)    0.00673471544479
  (0, 8532) 0.00403800859194
  (0, 34621)    0.0073385595246
  (0, 26664)    0.00430397987711
  (0, 11117)    0.00556197716333
  (0, 31960)    0.00637226762455
  (0, 14383)    0.00588259232191
  (0, 26636)    0.00546461963895
  : :
  (299, 30776)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 3574)   0.000926825754151
  (299, 31792)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 3531)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 3510)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 6746)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 1039)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 5055)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 15334)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 3591)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 3624)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 1468)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 791)    0.000463412877075
  (299, 3633)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 1260)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 1709)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 1717)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 862)    0.000463412877075
  (299, 854)    0.000463412877075
  (299, 19415)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 5142)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 4408)   0.000463412877075
  (299, 27294)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 15736)  0.000463412877075
  (299, 23403)  0.000926825754151
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nouraabdulaziz/PycharmProjects/untitled1/a.py", line 31, in <module>
    text_clf = text_clf.fit(text, reader.categories())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 207, in fit
    dtype=np.float64, order="C")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 531, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [300, 3]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You are sending `reader.categories()` for `y` which I think only returns distinct classes (targets) present. You need to send the label for each row of your `text`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works just fine.